# send REST message to pode in Openshift

Tags: java, kubernetes, openshift

I have an openshift namespace (`SomeNamespace`), in that namespace I have several pods.

I have a route associated with that namespace (`SomeRoute`).

In one of pods I have my spring application. It has REST controllers.

I want to send message to that REST controller, how can I do it?

I have a route URL: `https://some.namespace.company.name`. What should I find next?

I tried to send requests to `https://some.namespace.company.name/rest/api/route` but it didn't work. I guess, I must somehow specify pod in my URL, so route will redirect requests to concrete pod but I don't know how I can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify the pod in the route.

The chain goes like this:

- `Route` exposes a given port of a `Service`
- `Service` selects some pod to route the traffic to by its `.spec.selector` field

You need to check your `Service` and `Route` definitions.

Example service and route (including only the related parts of the resources):

`Service`

```
spec:
  ports:
  - name: 8080-tcp
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    <label-key>: <label-value>
```

Where `label-key` and `label-value` is any label key-value combination that selects your pod with the http application.

`Route`

```
spec:
  port:
    targetPort: 8080-tcp <port name of the service>
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: <service name>
```

When your app exposes some endpoint on `:8080/rest/api`, you can invoke it with `<route-url>/rest/api`

You can try it out with some example application (some I found randomly on github, to verify everything works correctly on your cluster):

- create a new app using s2i build from github repository: `oc new-app registry.redhat.io/openjdk/openjdk-11-rhel7~https://github.com/redhat-cop/spring-rest`
- wait until the s2i build is done and the pod is started
- expose the service via route: `oc expose svc/spring-rest`
- grab the route url: `oc get route spring-rest -o jsonpath='{.spec.host}'`
- invoke the api: `curl -k <route-url>/v1/greeting`
- response should be something like: `{"id":3,"content":"Hello, World!"}`

Comment: thanks a lot, now it much clearer! In my test application I communicated with my rest controller. Unfortunately I cant communicate with my working app, but I think there some different problem, since it worked with test app. Thx again!

Answer (score 1):

**Routes** are an **OpenShift-specific** way of exposing a Service outside the cluster.
But, if you are developing an app that will be deployed onto **OpenShift and Kubernetes**, then you should use **Kubernetes Ingress** objects.

Using Ingress means that your app’s manifests are more portable between different Kubernetes clusters.

From the [official Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/):

> - An Ingress may be configured to give Services externally-reachable URLs, load balance traffic, terminate SSL / TLS, and offer name-based virtual hosting.
> - Ingress exposes HTTP and HTTPS routes from outside the cluster to services within the cluster.
> - Traffic routing is controlled by rules defined on the Ingress resource.

##### So, if you want to reach your REST controllers:

- **from within the k8s cluster**. Create a k8s [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) to expose an application running on a set of Pods as a network service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
  namespace: your-namespace
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
```

This specification creates a new Service object named "my-service", which targets TCP port 8080 on any Pod with the `app=MyApp` label.
You can reach the REST controller using this URL:

```
http://my-service
```

- **externally**. Create an [Ingress resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) to configure externally-reachable URLs (a k8s Service 'my-service' should exist):

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-name
  namespace: your-namespace
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "foo.bar.com"  
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

You can reach the REST controller using this URL:

```
http://foo.bar.com
```

Comment: Thx for comment! I tried to implement the second approach, but it didnt work for me (I cant find external URL even with curl). Probably its because we have Istio-mesh in our project and somewhere Istio block all external requests to all services (except ingress-proxy)